# Add to cart configurable products using magento soap api V1

Tags: magento-1.8, api, soap, addtocart

Trying to add configurable product in magento cart using magento soap api V1 but not able to add the products. can anyone please let me know the way how to do it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you put your code.

Comment: This is how i am doing it - 
$arrProducts = array(
            'product_id' => "120",
            'sku' => 'ink',
            'qty' => '1',
           'options' => 
    array(
      'key' => 525,
      'value' => 99       
      ),
            'bundle_option' => null,
            'bundle_option_qty' => null,
            'links' => null
        );
$resultCartProductAdd = $proxy->call($sessionId, "cart_product.add", array($shoppingCartId, $arrProducts));

Comment: are you doing on configurable product ya bundle?

Comment: need to add all type of products  via soap including - configurable, bundle and grouped. just trying to start with configurable products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For add to cart of configurable product,you need to super attribute value. in my below if only one super attribute  so 
  in super_attribute i have set one value

```
$quoteId = $client->call( $session, 'cart.create',array( 'default' ));
$arrProducts = array(
    array(
        "product_id" =>"21",
        "qty" => 2,
                "super_attribute" => array(         
                    92 => 162

                 )
    )

);



$resultCartProductAdd = $client->call(
    $sessionId,
    "cart_product.add",
    array(
        $quoteId,
        $arrProducts
    )
);
```

**here 92 is attribute id and 162 it option id**
if you have more then one variance for  then

```
"super_attribute" => array(         
                    first_attribute_id => first_chose_option_value
                     seocnd_attribute_id => seocnd_chose_option_value.
                     .....



                 )
```

Comment: works like charm :) :)
You saved my day. Can you please give me an example of product array for bundled and grouped too?

Comment: accepted. Any idea about grouped and bundled?

Comment: sure.give u idea sortly

Comment: Is this working for associating simple to configurable products?

Comment: i use this code but it return me this message : please specify product options

Comment: @AmitBera  is it working with v2 api ?